# what is happening with my code when I try to insert my array ids?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am trying to do a table for notifications using codeigniter and node.js for push notifications from database ,but however I did an array which contains my product ids from my session cart , but one I send them through my function looks like this on error output

```
INSERT INTO storelte_notifications (message,type,product_id,user_id,timestamp) VALUES('low stock', 2, ('4169','4170','4173','4172','4175'), '1', 1499414552)
```

how could I send all together , but not as I am sending I want to send my ids and then store them together with my notifications table  my code looks like  this

notifications function

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->session->carrito = $this->sale->checar_existe_carrito();
        $array = $this->sale->get_all_cart($this->session->carrito);
        $product_id = array();
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
             $product_id[] = $value['id'];
        }
        $this->json($product_id);
        $this->notification->addNotification('low stock', $product_id, $this->session->log['id'], 'low stock',now());
    }
```

model

insert notifications

```
public function addNotification($message, $product_id, $user_id, $type = ''){
    $types = array('new' => 0, 'pending' => 1, 'low stock' => 2);
    if (isset($types[$type]) === false) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Value for third parameter must be one of new, pending, or low stock.');
    }
    $type = $types[$type];
    $timestamp = time();
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS notificationCount FROM storelte_notifications WHERE product_id IN ? AND type = ? ";
    $previousNotification = $this->db->query($query, array($product_id, $type))->result_array();
    if ($previousNotification[0]['notificationCount'] == 0) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO storelte_notifications (message,type,product_id,user_id,timestamp) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        try {
            if ($this->db->query($sql, array($message, $type, $product_id, $user_id, $timestamp))) {
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {

        }
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could write sql like this:

```
insert into storelte_notifications (message,type,product_id,user_id,timestamp) 
values ('low stock', 2, '4169', '1', 1499414552),('low stock', 2, '4170', '1', 1499414552)
```

or you could use foreach

Comment: foreach how can I do it if they are not in the same file., and also im using prepared statments

Answer (score 0):

Use a `foreach` loop:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO storelte_notifications (message,type,product_id,user_id,timestamp) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
try {
    foreach ($product_id as $pid) {
        if (!$this->db->query($sql, array($message, $type, $pid, $user_id, $timestamp))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
} catch (Exception $e) {

}
```